# Slider Images working correctly for right cursor but not left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a website for a friend which includes a slideshow with his most recent Instagram posts. The slideshow has a right and left arrow cursor.

The right cursor is working how I want it to; it shows each image from the array upon each click, and keeps going regardless of how many times the user clicks the right cursor. When it reaches the last image in the array, it starts at the first image again due to an if statement put in place.

However, I am having trouble with the left cursor and I suspect it is the counter variable? With the current code, what happens is when I click the left cursor (with the page refreshed and without even clicking on the right cursor), it goes to the second image in the array `index1`, rather than the last. Then I click the left cursor again without any change happening, then when I click it the third time it goes to the last image in the array and works as it should until it reaches the second image in the array again - because after that it does not go to the first image, it skips the first image after another click of nothing happening and then goes to the last image in the array. Repeats itself in that manner (sorry for going so in-detail, but I want people to get an idea of whats happening here if the code doesn't help).

```js
var sliderImages = [];
var counter = 1;

sliderImages[0] = "images/i1.png";
sliderImages[1] = "images/i2.png";
sliderImages[2] = "images/i3.png";
sliderImages[3] = "images/i4.png";
sliderImages[4] = "images/i5.png";

$("#right-arrow").click(function() {

  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);
  counter++;
  $('#count').text(counter);
  if (counter >= sliderImages.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

});

$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);
  counter--;
  if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = sliderImages.length
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="instagram-feed">
  <div class="container">

    <h2>INSTAGRAM GALLERY</h2>
    <div class="insta-gallery">

      <img src="images/left-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="left-arrow">
      <img src="images/i1.png" class="active">
      <img src="images/right-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="right-arrow">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should put that in a `Snippet` for us to view

Comment: When your script loads, `counter = 1`. The first thing your `left-arrow` click does is set the image `src` to the corresponding index in the array. A `counter` of 1 will set your slider to the second item in the array.

Comment: Hi Zak, sorry I am new to stack overflow and have to get used to these things. Thanks for pointing it out though. Will keep that in mind with every future post.

Comment: @jimmy118 You should initialize the page with `counter = 0` instead of `counter = 1`. Your left and right arrow clicks should modify counter *first*, and *then* update the `src`. Additionally, you'll likely want `sliderImages.length - 1`.

Comment: Santi, thanks for your response. Thank you to others who responded too. When I change the code as you have suggested, Santi, the right curosor works up until I reach the very last image in the array. On this last image, I click the right cursor and nothing happens. Then I click it again - the reason nothing happened is because it skipped the first image in the array - and moves onto the second. It repeates itself in this manner. The left cursor does the same thing, it mirrors the behaviour of the right cursor, except the image which it skips after two clicks is the last image in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page loads, you set `counter` to `1`. When you click the left-arrow button, the first thing you do is set the image to the `counter` value, and so you set the image to `1`. (Remember, arrays are 0-indexed, meaning `1` refers to the *second* item).

You'd be better off if `counter` was referring to the current image, not trying to assume the *upcoming* one. See my comments in the modified code below for more information.

```js
var sliderImages = [];
var counter = 0;         //Start with first image instead of second

sliderImages[0] = "images/i1.png";
sliderImages[1] = "images/i2.png";
sliderImages[2] = "images/i3.png";
sliderImages[3] = "images/i4.png";
sliderImages[4] = "images/i5.png";

$("#right-arrow").click(function() {
  counter++;                                           //Moving forward by one
  if (counter > sliderImages.length-1) counter = 0;    //Wrap-around if we exceed length-1
  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);     //Update img src
});

$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
  counter--;                                           //Moving backward by one
  if (counter < 0) counter = sliderImages.length-1;    //Wrap-around if negative
  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);     //Update img src
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="instagram-feed">
  <div class="container">

    <h2>INSTAGRAM GALLERY</h2>
    <div class="insta-gallery">

      <img src="images/left-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="left-arrow">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="active">
      <img src="images/right-arrow.png" class="arrow" id="right-arrow">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Santi! I fully appreciate you breaking down each point as well. It helps with my education and growing my knowledge on the mistakes I am encountering. Very helpful. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Use a ***counter*** as if you're handling **indexes**, so set it initially at `0`.

Here's the basic logic:

```js
var sliderImages = [
  "//placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=O",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/f0b?text=1",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/0fb?text=2",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/fb0?text=3",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/b0f?text=4"
];

var n = sliderImages.length; // Total slides
var c = 0;                   // Counter

function anim () {
  $("#mainImage").attr("src", sliderImages[c]);
}

$("#prev").on("click", function() {
  --c;                      // Pre-decrement
  if ( c < 0 ) { c = n-1; } // If lower than 0 - go to last slide 
  anim();                   // animate
});

$("#next").on("click", function() {
  ++c;                      // Pre-increment
  if ( c > n-1 ) { c = 0; }   // If greater than num of slides - go to first slide
  anim();                   // animate
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="mainImage" src="//placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=O">

<br>
<button id="prev">&larr;</button>
<button id="next">&rarr;</button>

<span id="count"></span>
```

Or here's a neater extracted **formula** of the above:

```js
var sliderImages = [
  "//placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=O",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/f0b?text=1",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/0fb?text=2",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/fb0?text=3",
  "//placehold.it/100x100/b0f?text=4"
];

var n = sliderImages.length; // Total slides
var c = 0;                   // Counter

function anim () {
  c = c<0 ? n-1 : c%n;                          // Fix counter
  $("#mainImage").attr("src", sliderImages[c]); // Animate (or whatever)
}

$("#prev, #next").on("click", function() {
  c = this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c;             // Increement or decrement
  anim();                                       // Animate 
});

// If you have bullets than you can simply do like:
$(".bullet").on("click", function() {
  c = $(this).index();
  anim();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="mainImage" src="//placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=O">

<br>
<button id="prev">&larr;</button>
<button id="next">&rarr;</button>

<span id="count"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated your code a bit :

```
var sliderImages = [];
var counter = 0;

sliderImages[0] = "images/i1.png";
sliderImages[1] = "images/i2.png";
sliderImages[2] = "images/i3.png";
sliderImages[3] = "images/i4.png";
sliderImages[4] = "images/i5.png";

$("#right-arrow").click(function() {
  counter++;
  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);
  $('#count').text(counter);
  if (counter >= sliderImages.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

});

$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
  counter--;
  $(".active").attr("src", sliderImages[counter]);
  if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = sliderImages.length - 1;
  }

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering a question, make sure you explain what you've changed and how it fixes OP's issue(s). When you post a code-only answer, it becomes a game of "spot-the-difference", which doesn't help OP or future readers.

Comment: Thank you Santi for pointing out the mistakes that I am making as a newbie to this community.